# Unable to retrieve Virtual Network ID from Snowflake Account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As mentioned in the official snowflake documentation [1], I was trying to get the IDs of the Virtual Network in which my Snowflake Account is Located.

However, while executing the query, I am getting "SQL compilation error". Can someone provide some pointers pls?

```
select system$get_snowflake_platform_info();
SQL compilation error: Unknown function SYSTEM$GET_SNOWFLAKE_PLATFORM_INFO
```

[1] https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_get_snowflake_platform_info.html

Comment: Are you using **accountadmin** role? Most probably you're under a different role.

Comment: I am using SYSADMIN Role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you linked to clearly states that this function only returns data when using the ACCOUNTADMIN role